# Blank page on a laravel specific route

Tags: php, laravel

I know this is probably a newbie question, but I can't find any solution.

I have a specific route defined in my app/routes.php like this :

```
Route::get('videos', 'MovieController@showMovies');
```

When my Laravel app is going to the 'videos' URL, I have just a blank page.

I don't know why, but nothing append. I've put some `var_dump` in my showMovies function, but nothing is on my page.

My showMovies function is really simple :

```
public function showMovies(){

    $movies = Movie::all();

    $params = array(
        "movies" => $movies
    );

    return View::make('front.videos', $params);

}
```

I've set debug to true and correct the permissions for storage writing, but I've got no logs.

Comment: anything else is working?

Comment: Yes, all my others routes worked. That's why I don't understand..

Comment: You should verify that `front.videos` template exists.

Comment: Yes, the template exists.

Comment: But my app doesn't go to the showMovies function. Nothing happens..

Comment: Please add the entire controller class and all the routes.. I can't guess anything right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you have a folder in your `public` directory called `videos`. That can sometimes be a pain in the butt to debug.

Comment: No problem, happy coding! :-)